# Android - Horizontally (right-to-left) circular background color transition

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know how can I implement this animation?

Small image frame and text movement is independent from the animation. It's just like simple pager action with some scale and alpha transformation. Only problem is the color change of background like this.

I'm open to both XML and Jetpack Compose way solutions. Please..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution**

After lots of hours searching, I've found the perfect one;

https://github.com/2307vivek/BubblePager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**My Solution**

```
import android.graphics.Path
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.annotation.FloatRange
import androidx.compose.animation.core.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Outline
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asComposePath
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInteropFilter
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection
import kotlin.math.hypot

@Composable
fun <T> CircularReveal(
    targetState: T,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    animationSpec: FiniteAnimationSpec<Float> = tween(),
    content: @Composable (T) -> Unit,
) {
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState, label = "Circular reveal")
    transition.CircularReveal(modifier, animationSpec, content = content)
}

@Composable
fun <T> Transition<T>.CircularReveal(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    animationSpec: FiniteAnimationSpec<Float> = tween(),
    content: @Composable (targetState: T) -> Unit,
) {
    var offset: Offset? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
    val currentlyVisible = remember { mutableStateListOf<T>().apply { add(currentState) } }
    val contentMap = remember {
        mutableMapOf<T, @Composable () -> Unit>()
    }
    if (currentState == targetState) {
        // If not animating, just display the current state
        if (currentlyVisible.size != 1 || currentlyVisible[0] != targetState) {
            // Remove all the intermediate items from the list once the animation is finished.
            currentlyVisible.removeAll { it != targetState }
            contentMap.clear()
        }
    }
    if (!contentMap.contains(targetState)) {
        // Replace target with the same key if any
        val replacementId = currentlyVisible.indexOfFirst {
            it == targetState
        }
        if (replacementId == -1) {
            currentlyVisible.add(targetState)
        } else {
            currentlyVisible[replacementId] = targetState
        }
        contentMap.clear()
        currentlyVisible.forEach { stateForContent ->
            contentMap[stateForContent] = {
                val progress by animateFloat(
                    label = "Progress",
                    transitionSpec = { animationSpec }
                ) {
                    val targetedContent = stateForContent != currentlyVisible.last() || it == stateForContent
                    if (targetedContent) 1f else 0f
                }
                Box(Modifier.circularReveal(progress = progress, offset = offset)) {
                    content(stateForContent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.pointerInteropFilter {
            if (it.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (!started) offset = Offset(it.x, it.y)
            }
            started
        }
    ) {
        currentlyVisible.forEach {
            key(it) {
                contentMap[it]?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}

private val <T> Transition<T>.started get() =
    currentState != targetState || isRunning

fun Modifier.circularReveal(
    @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) progress: Float,
    offset: Offset? = null,
) = clip(CircularRevealShape(progress, offset))

class CircularRevealShape(
    @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) private val progress: Float,
    private val offset: Offset? = null,
) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ): Outline {
        return Outline.Generic(Path().apply {
            addCircle(
                offset?.x ?: (size.width / 2f),
                offset?.y ?: (size.height / 2f),
                longestDistanceToACorner(size, offset) * progress,
                Path.Direction.CW
            )
        }.asComposePath())
    }

    private fun longestDistanceToACorner(size: Size, offset: Offset?): Float {
        if (offset == null) {
            return hypot(size.width / 2f, size.height / 2f)
        }

        val topLeft = hypot(offset.x, offset.y)
        val topRight = hypot(size.width - offset.x, offset.y)
        val bottomLeft = hypot(offset.x, size.height - offset.y)
        val bottomRight = hypot(size.width - offset.x, size.height - offset.y)

        return topLeft.coerceAtLeast(topRight).coerceAtLeast(bottomLeft).coerceAtLeast(bottomRight)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CircularRevealAnimationPreview() {
    val isSystemDark = isSystemInDarkTheme()
    var darkTheme by remember { mutableStateOf(isSystemDark) }
    val onThemeToggle = { darkTheme = !darkTheme }

    CircularReveal(
        targetState = darkTheme,
        animationSpec = tween(1500)
    ) { isDark ->
        MyAppTheme(darkTheme = isDark) {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
                onClick = onThemeToggle
            ) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(120.dp),
                        imageVector = if (isDark) Icons.Default.DarkMode else Icons.Default.LightMode,
                        contentDescription = "Toggle",
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's cool, but not the exact thing I'm looking for

Comment: how did you come up with that in 10 minutes?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time. You can develop using this structure. I hope it meets your needs. Don't forget to vote. Thank you.

Comment: @TomBerghuis yes, I did come up with that in less than 10 mins. Typed source code is not the solution for this problem (testing this kind of source code is not hard in 10 min, looks like it is for you), though it's mentioned as "solution"..

Comment: @ArdaKazancı thanks for your effort. I'm working on it

Comment: I understand you, but I just wanted to say that I don't have time to work on a customizable script. Best regards

Comment: @ArdaKazancı that's understandable, don't worry, please. Thanks for the help, man. It's up voted already by me

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope you get the result you want as soon as possible. Good luck.

Comment: I voted for the question.

Comment: @AyxanVəliyev I am in awe of your speed. something like that would take me a week

Comment: @AyxanVəliyev Well the question about the "10 minutes" was probably directed to Arda. But of course, testing this code can be done in 10 minutes, but it is unlikely that this specific code was written from scratch in 10 minutes.